# How do I get the current module/script/file name in GNU Smalltalk?

Tags: filenames, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

GNU Smalltalk omits the script name in argv.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gst -f

| argv program |

argv := Smalltalk arguments.

(argv size) > 0 ifTrue: [
    program := argv at: 1.

    Transcript show: 'Program: ', program; cr.
] ifFalse: [
    Transcript show: 'argv = {}'; cr.
]

$ ./scriptname.st
argv = {}
```

I see two ways to get the script name:

- Track down some Smalltalk method which returns the script name akin to Perl's variable `$0`.
- Track down syntax for a multiline shebang and force GST to supply the scriptname as the first member of argv. Here's an example in [Common Lisp](https://github.com/mcandre/scriptedmain/blob/master/scriptedmain.lisp).

Comment: Post your questions to the GNU Smalltalk mailing list and you're quite likely to benefit from the knowledge and experience of those who implement GST http://smalltalk.gnu.org/community/ml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best that can be done is use shebangs to force the script name to ARGV, then check whether `Smalltalk getArgv: 1` ends with a hardcoded string.

Posted here and on [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptedMain#Smalltalk).

```
"exec" "gst" "-f" "$0" "$0" "$@"
"exit"

Object subclass: ScriptedMain [
    ScriptedMain class >> meaningOfLife [ ^42 ]
]

| main |

main := [
    Transcript show: 'Main: The meaning of life is ', ((ScriptedMain meaningOfLife) printString); cr.
].

(((Smalltalk getArgc) > 0) and: [ ((Smalltalk getArgv: 1) endsWith: 'scriptedmain.st') ]) ifTrue: [
    main value.
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the current method where it comes from: `thisContext method methodSourceFile printNl`.

Comment: That's helpful, but it doesn't work well with scriptedmain (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/ScriptedMain#Smalltalk), because that doesn't tell you which file was run with `gst somefile.st`.

Comment: Thanks for joining the GNU Smalltalk mailing list. When I Google my newbie questions I often see you asking the same questions in the mailing list archives.